# Matlabs evaluation of any and all with an empty vector give different answers

Tags: matlab

Any and all on an empty should give the same answer. Yet here they give a different answer and all of and empty is true. Can anyone explain this behaviour of matlabs (tested on version 2010a->2012b).

> >> any([])
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  0
> ```

but

> >> all([])
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  1
> ```

Comment: The behavior is by definition of functions, but even I would like to know, what is the purpose behind defining like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`any` and `all` on the empty array should absolutely not give the same answers - MATLAB's behaviour is both documented and correct.

`any(A)` means "there exists an element of `A` that is true", in other words

```
∃x∈A x is true
```

Since there are no elements in `A`, it correctly returns `false`.

`all(A)` means "for all elements in `A`, that element is true", in other words

```
∀x∈A x is true
```

Perhaps this is less intuitive, but since there are no elements in `A`, that sentence is true - and MATLAB correctly returns `true`. Any textbook on first-order logic will confirm this.

If you'd like a case where MATLAB's behaviour really does seem wrong, and contradictory to the above, try

```
>> if [] disp('hello'); else disp('bye'); end
bye
```

In all other cases, `if X` is `true` when all the elements of `X` are true. But when `X` is `[]`, `if` behaves differently. That's also documented.

Comment: ah I Had a bit of a eureka moment. The same principal also forms part of our law system innocent till proven guilty. Thus all is true until it sees a false. Any is false until it sees a true. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Note that when A is empty, "all x in A are true", "all x in A are false", "all x in A are not equal to x" and "all x in A are Santa Claus" are all true sentences.

Answer (score 5):

This behaviour is explicitly documented:

- From http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/any.html:

  > If `A` is empty, `any(A)` returns logical `0` (`false`).
- From http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/all.html:

  > If `A` is empty, `all(A)` returns logical `1` (`true`).

I suppose the behaviour of `all` is slightly counterintuitive.  At a guess, I'd say the intention is for the following equivalence to hold, for symmetry:

```
~all(A) == any(~A)
```

Comment: Ok its documented but @SamRoberts gets to the underlying logic